# How to make related_name to User's Model in Django? I want to query username from anothe model

Tags: django-rest-framework

The aim is to show the lessons that were inserted only by the current user which is: user_author_lesson. The user_author_lesson is actually a Foreign key to the User model. I want to query the username field in the serializer queryset. Or maybe there is another way to implement that. Thank you.

models

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import date


class Student(models.Model):

   
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    information = models.TextField(blank=True)
    user_author_student = models.ForeignKey(
        User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objects = models.Manager()  # default manager


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-first_name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name


class Lesson(models.Model):

 
    options = (
        ('paid', 'Paid'),
        ('not paid', 'Not Paid'),
    )
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lessons')
    paid = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, choices=options, default='not paid')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    task1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description1 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    task2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description2 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    user_author_lesson = models.ForeignKey(
        User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lesson_date = models.DateField(default=date.today, null=False)
    objects = models.Manager()  # default manager
   
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-lesson_date',)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s: %s %s %s' % (self.student, self.title, self.lesson_date, self.paid)
```

views

```
from django.http import request
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.serializers import Serializer
from private_models.models import Lesson, Student
from .serializers import LessonSerializer, LessonDetailSerializer, StudentDetailSerializer, StuSerializer, CreateLessonSerializer,DeleteLessonSerializer
from rest_framework.permissions import SAFE_METHODS, DjangoModelPermissions, BasePermission, AllowAny
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


class LessonUserWritePermission(BasePermission):
    message = 'editing lesson is restricted to the authors only'

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return obj.user_author_lesson == request.user


class LessonList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
   
    # permission_classes = [DjangoModelPermissions]
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Lesson.objects.all()
    
    #queryset = Lesson.objects.filter(user_author_lesson=request.user.username).all()
    
    serializer_class = LessonSerializer
    #print(self.request.user)
    #def get_queryset(self):
    #    print(queryset.objects.filter(user_author_lesson=self.request.user))
    #    return Lesson.objects.filter(user_author_lesson=).all()


class StuDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentDetailSerializer
    # def get_object(self, queryset=None, **kwargs):
    #     item = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    #     return get_object_or_404(Student, pk=item)


class StuList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    # permission_classes = [DjangoModelPermissions]
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StuSerializer


class LessonDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    # class LessonDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView, LessonUserWritePermission):
    # the above line is to use when i fix the user permissions!!!
    # permission_classes = [LessonUserWritePermission]
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Lesson.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LessonDetailSerializer


class CreateLesson(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Lesson.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CreateLessonSerializer

class DeleteLesson(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes =[AllowAny]  
    queryset = Lesson.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DeleteLessonSerializer
```

serializers

```
from rest_framework import serializers, fields
from private_models.models import Lesson, Student



class LessonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    student = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    user_author_lesson = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)

    # def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    #     try:
    #         if self.context['request'].method in ['GET']:
    #             self.fields['student'] = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    #     except KeyError:
    #         pass

    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = ('id', 'student', 'title', 'lesson_date',
                  'paid', 'user_author_lesson')

    def get_student(self, obj):
        
        return obj.student.first_name

    def post():
        pass    


class LessonDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = ('id', 'student', 'title', 'task1', 'description1',
                  'task2', 'description2', 'lesson_date', 'paid',)


class StudentDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lessons = LessonSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Student

        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'information', 'lessons')


class StuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_author_student = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        # lessons = LessonDetailSerializer(many=True)
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                  'information', 'user_author_student')


class CreateLessonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # student = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    student_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = ('student_id', 'title', 'task1', 'description1',
                  'task2', 'description2', 'lesson_date', 'paid',)

class DeleteLessonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
          model = Lesson
          fields =('student_id', 'title', 'task1', 'description1',
                  'task2', 'description2', 'lesson_date', 'paid',)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a LessonsViewset and define a get_queryset method like so:

```
class LessonViewsets(viewsets.ModelViewset):
    queryset = Lesson.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LessonSerializer
    permission_classes = []

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().get_queryset()
        student_id = Student.objects.get(
        users_lessons = Lesson.objects.select_related.("student").filter(student=self.request.user.id)
        return users_lessons
```

The viewsets from DRF is much effective. However you can use the ListCreateAPIView; just define the get_queryset method to return only lessons associated to the authenticated user.

Comment: Thank you.So I need to make  UserSerializer class?

Comment: Pardon me, it should be LessonSerializers not UseeSerializer. Do you know how to configure the serializer? Let me know

Comment: my get_queryset has to filter the user_author_lesson and I couldn't implement it because the foreign key has no related_name.

Comment: I see. Then, do this: go to your Lesson model; in your user_author lesson, do: user_author lesson = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="lesson", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: the current user is the user_author_lesson, and I wish to display only his data insertions meaning the lessons he entered. The students are not relevant.So I tried to make the get_queryset, but how to filter it? (I am used to flask..) I can't filter by user_author_lesson because it returns nothing and says it expects an integer If I remember.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying

Comment: I just edited the answer I gave by adding an 'id'. Do that and let me know what next....

Comment: It doesn't work. Maybe I don't need a related name. but how to use get_queryset to show current user data?

Comment: there is an advance.because no it says no data, and before it just came up with nothing on screen and the error Typerror something like that.It means the id is not the current user

Comment: Okay. You must be logged in with the account of a registered user.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to make the reverse queries.

By default `django` allows you to make the reverse queries using default-related names which is `<ModelName>_set`.

for e.g. if you want to `fetch all the lessons` against some `user`.

`user_instance.lesson_set.all()`

Try to rewrite the `LessonList` View class as:

```
class LessonList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
   
    # permission_classes = [DjangoModelPermissions]
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Lesson.objects.all()
    
    serializer_class = LessonSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.request.user.lesson_set.all()
```

[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) has more useful examples.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it. I also encountered the preform_create function that I think I need in order to determine the user that entered the lesson.